# select all by where clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Here is my code ,

```
 Name obj = new Name();
 obj = DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20 ).SingleOrDefault();
```

What I want to do is to update all the `Name` with `age=20` ,

```
 obj.Name = " Mr " + obj.Name ;
 DB.SubmitChanges();
```

But `.SingleOrDefault()` can return only one value , I want to get all with `age=20` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Where()` already returns all of the matching items. You don't need to add anything else. Try this:

```
foreach(var item in DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20 ))
{
   item.Name = " Mr " + item.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20 )` returns an `IEnumerable<Name>` that you can iterate over with `foreach` to modify each entry.

Comment: Sure, give @JLRishe the accepted answer just because s/he assumes you can't implement a `foreach` loop. ;)

Comment: :) , but is it perfect more ?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using `SingleOrDefault`? Try this:

```
var result = DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Where` will return list matching condition

```
List<Name> nameList = DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20);
foreach(var name in nameList )
{
    name.Name = " Mr " + name.Name ;
}
DB.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

> But .SingleOrDefault() can return only one value , I want to get all
>   with age=20 .

Yes, So remove `SingleOrDefault()` you will get all the records match with the condition
And also you can then try to use `Foreach` to update each and every item you filtered from the initial names.

try below code :

```
DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20 ).ToList().ForEach(n=>n.Name = " Mr " + n.Name);
```

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Unfortunately, it doesn't compile because IEnumerable<T> has no `Foreach()` method.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad It can be done with `DB.Names.Where(x => x.age == 20 ).ToList().ForEach(n=>n.Name = " Mr " + n.Name);` (note the `ToList()` and capitalization of "Each"), but SO superstar Eric Lippert [is not a fan of that style](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).